# Why do all template instantiations need to be complete to resolve function overload?

Tags: c++

This question requires quite a long setup, but bear with me.

Consider following files:

**Type1.hpp**

```
#ifndef TYPE1_HPP
#define TYPE1_HPP

struct Type1
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

#endif
```

**Type2.hpp**

```
#ifndef TYPE2_HPP
#define TYPE2_HPP

struct Type2
{
    int c;
    int d;
};

#endif
```

**MyTemplate.hpp**

```
#ifndef MYTEMPLATE_HPP
#define MYTEMPLATE_HPP

template <typename T>
struct MyTemplate
{
    T t;
};

#endif
```

**Functions.hpp**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_HPP
#define FUNCTIONS_HPP

struct Type1;
struct Type2;
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate;

int func(const MyTemplate<Type1>& param);
int func(const MyTemplate<Type2>& param);

#endif
```

**Functions.cpp**

```
#include "Functions.hpp"
#include "MyTemplate.hpp"
#include "Type1.hpp"
#include "Type2.hpp"

int func(const MyTemplate<Type1>& param)
{
    return param.t.a + param.t.b;
}

int func(const MyTemplate<Type2>& param)
{
    return param.t.c - param.t.d;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Functions.hpp"
#include "MyTemplate.hpp"
#include "Type1.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    MyTemplate<Type1> x;
    x.t.a = 1;
    x.t.b = 2;

    int y = func(x);

    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled with Clang:

```
clang++-3.6 -o testover -std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp Functions.cpp
```

results in compilation error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
./MyTemplate.hpp:7:7: error: field has incomplete type 'Type2'
    T t;
      ^
main.cpp:12:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'MyTemplate<Type2>' requested here
    int y = func(x);
             ^
./Functions.hpp:5:8: note: forward declaration of 'Type2'
struct Type2;
       ^
1 error generated.
```

When the second function's name in Functions.hpp and cpp is changed to `func2`, the code compiles.

My question is: why do compilers require different information here with overloaded functions compared to two functions with different names?

Comment: The rules for overload resolution require working out who's convertible to what in how many steps, and you can only figure out if and how `MyTemplate<Type2>` is convertible to `MyTemplate<Type1>` and vice versa if you know the type definitions.

Comment: But if I change `MyTemplate` to `std:vector` the code compiles. Shouldn't the compiler know the `Type1` <-> `Type2` conversions also in that case?

Comment: The problem is that `MyTemplate` cannot be specialized for incomplete types. Strictly speaking, neither can `std::vector`, but that's just UB and your implementation happens to allow it.

Comment: With regards to vector, I suspect that it's because internally, the vector will only have a T*, not an instance of T. It's perfectly fine to operate on pointers to undefined types, as you can see in this example by modifying MyTemplate accordingly.

Comment: `vector` case is equivalent to having `template <typename T> struct MyTemplate { T* t; };`, which does not require class `T` definition: https://godbolt.org/z/fnTdWvb3d